# Datatables not displaying properly in MVC6

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I'm currently playing first fun with MVC6 and I'm having some trouble with Datatables. As far as I can tell I have included everything that ought to be there but every time I try to run the code I get an error saying that the jquery.datatables.min cant see Jquery.

Code is as follows:

```
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

$(document).ready( function () {

    $('#datatable2').DataTable();

} );

</script>

<table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="datatable2" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Problem Description</th>
    <th>Solution</th>
</tr>

@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProblemID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProblemDescription)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Solution)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Any thoughts? It's probably something really obvious...

*And I know scripts should normally be in _layout, this is just a test project to get a feel for the changes between MVC 5 & 6.

Comment: try the following: put jquery as your first script, then the datatables script. add `<body></body>` to your table. Take a look at the docs: https://www.datatables.net/manual/installation

Comment: Both good points - and ones I should have thought of... now we get: 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'DataTable'

Comment: you have included `datatable.js` before `jquery.min.js` duhhh.. :D first fix that.

Comment: another thing worth mentioning is putting your scripts together in the `@section scripts { }`

Answer (score 0):

Try as below

For more information follow this list [dataTables js Example](https://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html)

**INCLUDE FILES IN THIS WAY**

1) jquery.dataTables.min.css,

2) jquery-2.2.0.min.js,

3) jquery.dataTables.min.js

```
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

**HTML**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="datatable2" cellspacing="0">
   <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Problem Description</th>
        <th>Solution</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
        @foreach(var item in Model)
        {
           <tr>
               <td>
                   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProblemID)
               </td>
               <td>
                   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProblemDescription)
               </td>
               <td>
                   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Solution)
               </td>
          </tr>
        }
   </tbody>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">    
    $(document).ready( function () {    
        $('#datatable2').DataTable();    
    });    
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. No dice unfortunately - I'm still getting 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'DataTable'

Comment: follow this link it might be helpful to solve your issue http://stackoverflow.com/a/15759205/2798643

Comment: Seemed like a good suggestion given the amount of random stuff I've tried, but I went through and removed everything and it's still no good